# Python: Tkinter - One animation stops when the other begins

Tags: python, tkinter

```
for plusOneFrames in range(0, 25):
    xxUL = xxUL + 0  
    yyUL = yyUL - 5

    myText = screen.create_text( xxUL, yyUL, text = "+1", font = "Arial 25", fill = "black"  )
    screen.update()
    sleep(0.05)
    screen.delete( myText )
screen.delete( myText )
```

So basically, it makes a +1 float up whenever the user clicks, but whenever one goes up and I click again, the +1 that was already going up stops in its place and just sits there. If I click again it does the same until theres hundreds. How can I make it so that it never stops the animation even though its all in one for loop?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not just a random fragment of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `sleep` in the middle of a Tkinter callback without making the entire program stop running. After all, that's exactly what `sleep(0.05)` means: make the entire program stop running for 0.05 seconds.

And it's not just `sleep`—no matter what this function does, while it's running, that's the code that's running; no other code gets to run, so your UI is otherwise frozen.

There are two basic solutions:

- Change your function so that it does one step of the animation, schedules the next step to run as a callback in 0.05 seconds, and returns.
- Use a background thread.

The second one may seem simpler, but unfortunately Tkinter is kind of a pain to use in a multithreaded app. So, let's do the first one. Something like this:

```
def nextframe(i):
    nonlocal xxUL, yyUL
    xxUL = xxUL + 0  
    yyUL = yyUL - 5

    myText = screen.create_text( xxUL, yyUL, text = "+1", font = "Arial 25", fill = "black"  )
    screen.update()
    screen.delete( myText )
    i += 1
    if i != 25:
        screen.after(0.05, lambda: nextframe(i))
    else:
        screen.delete( myText )

nextframe(0)
```

(I don't know if the exact details here will work with your actual code—in fact, if your code is not using Python 3.0+, or you're not doing this locally inside another function, I know it won't work. But since you didn't show your actual code, I have to make some guesses and hope you can understand how to adapt it.)

See [Why your GUI app freezes](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/10/why-your-gui-app-freezes.html) for more details, or google for a good tutorial on event loops or event-driven programming.